# Am I missing something? You can't have accessible em vs px media queries for <link> or @import?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, width, accessibility

In terms of speed, I only want to download CSS for screen sizes as they are needed. For accessibility, I want the media query to use em instead of px since users can change the browser font size.

Say you use the `@media` at-rule in your CSS; you cannot do an `@import` inside of it.

```
@media (min-width: 37.5625em) {
    /* Congrats, you force downloading tons of rules */
}
```

Say you use an `@import` at-rule in your CSS; you cannot use `em` units in its media query. You have to use `px`.

```
@import url('tablets-plus.css') (min-width: 601px);
/* Congrats, you fail to provide accessibility for users who change the default font size */
```

Say you use a `<link>`-element in the HTML; again can't use `em`, have to use `px`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tablets-plus.css" media="screen and (min-width: 601px)">
<!-- Congrats, you fail to provide accessibility for users who change the default font size -->
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This could cause circular references.

Comment: D. Pardal - can you elaborate?

Comment: That stylesheet could contain code that modifies the `font-size`, making the media query not match.

Comment: The fact that you "want the media query to use em instead of px since users can change the browser font size" does not make sense.  What does the font size changing have to do with the page width?

Comment: @D.Pardal is right - circular references could be a huge problem. Imagine if you set your base font size to 16px and had a break point at 800px. Then increased the font size at that break point to 20px. So you would set your break-point at 50em, but then you update the font size to 20px so your break point now becomes 1000px (50em still, just em units have changed) and isn't valid, so your font-size reduces to 16px....etc.

Comment: @AlexW em is not a fixed size measurement, if you change the font-size, also em changes. Best way to check this if you use Firefox and zoom with "only increase font-size" enabled.   Regarding the original question: You miss that CSS is getting cached. So unless you have a really big CSS file you shouldn't care about these extra rules. If you do mobile (or desktop) first and only change what's necessary then the extra CSS won't be too big. And it won't affect performance since all non matching mediaqueries are ignored by the browser.

Comment: Well aware, but doesn't explain why OP is using a dynamically sized unit to try to measure screen sizes which are fixed size